# SQL Table Structure for news site

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to make a fast table structure for news site with php and mysql. My database structure is ID, title, content, cat_ids (; separedet IDs of categories - ;5;10;15;20;), active, publish_date.

I want to make a fast query to select news from this table. Something like that:

```
SELECT id 
FROM news 
WHERE cat_ids LIKE '%;15;%' 
  AND active = 1 
  AND publish_date < NOW() 
ORDER by publish_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

But if my table is 2-3GB the query is very slow. I need some ideas to make structure and make the select faster.

Comment: Don't use 'LIKE' - it doesn't use indexes.

Comment: I must user LIKE and I use indexes :)

Comment: @KostadinBuglow you *must use* like? no, you must normalize your schema

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cat_ids` column, try creating a `news_cats` table with `news_id` and `cat_id`, and using this query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM news JOIN news_cats ON news_id = id
WHERE cat_id = 15
  AND active = 1 
  AND publish_date < NOW() 
ORDER by publish_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions as below:

1) Create index on `"active"` field
2) Create index on `"publish_date"` field
3) Create separate table for category and news relation and remove `"cat_ids"` field from news table

New table might look like below:

**`news_category_ids`**

news_id
category_id

It can have multiple rows for each news_id, if news item falls in 3 categories, it will have 3 rows

Then use SQL like below:

```
SELECT news.id 
FROM news INNER JOIN news_category_ids ON news.id =  news_category_ids.news_id
WHERE 1
  AND news.active = 1 
  AND news_category_ids.cat_id = 15
  AND news.publish_date < NOW() 
ORDER by news.publish_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```